# When is the travel bubble between New Zealand and Australia opening?

Tags: international-travel, australia, covid-19, new-zealand, quarantine

With Covid, the borders have been closed since March 24, 2020.

There's a sort of one way bubble where you don't need to quarantine entering Australia, but what about the other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has been announced that you can travel from Australia to New Zealand without having to quarantine [from April 18, 2021 at 11:59pm](https://covid19.govt.nz/travel-and-the-border/quarantine-free-travel/quarantine-free-travel-with-australia/).

Answer (score 4):

This week, NZ Prime Minister Jacinda Ardern announced it would be happening in Q1, 2021, so before the end of March.

Source: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/dec/14/jacinda-ardern-new-zealand-and-australia-to-launch-travel-bubble-in-early-2021

This presumes no further outbreaks.

Comment: This may well change given the current cluster in NSW...

Comment: @Nick indeed :(

Comment: Coming up on the end of Q1 now, is this still the plan?

Comment: @Midavalo it's interesting, there's suddenly this week a massive amount of pressure from the other govt parties to open.  The National Party even started a petition on the matter.  The govt claims they're just finalising details like what happens if new cases are discovered.  We'll see.